# TensorFlow : optimizer gives nan as ouput

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, python-3.6, gradient-descent

I am running a very simple tensorflow program

```
W = tf.Variable([.3],tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3],tf.float32)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

linear_model = W*x + b

y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

squared_error = tf.square(linear_model - y)

loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_error)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)

train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as s:
    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('../../tfLogs/graph',s.graph)
    s.run(init)
    for i in range(1000):
        s.run(train,{x:[1,2,3,4],y:[0,-1,-2,-3]})
    print(s.run([W,b]))
```

this gives me

`[array([ nan], dtype=float32), array([ nan], dtype=float32)]`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_error)` instead of `reduce_mean`.  With `reduce_sum` your loss gets bigger when you have more data, and even with this small example it means your gradient is big enough to cause your model to diverge.

Something else which can cause this type of problem is when your learning rate is too large.  In this case you can also fix it by changing your learning rate from 0.1 to 0.01, but if you're still using `reduce_sum` it will break again when you add more points.