# TensorFlow: GradientDescentOptimizer Gives nan output

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to do a simple linear regression using Tensorflow. I am trying to use the `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` to minimize the mean squared loss function. I wrote the following code-

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=" ")
W = tf.Variable([.3], dtype=np.float32)
b = tf.Variable([-.3], dtype=np.float32)
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32)
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=np.float32)

np.random.shuffle(data)
brkpt = int(0.8*len(data))
Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest = data[:brkpt,0], data[brkpt:,0], data[:brkpt, 1], data[brkpt:, 1]
n = len(Xtrain)
Ypred = W*X + b

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y-Ypred))

opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(loss)

initial = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(initial)
    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run(opt, feed_dict={X: Xtrain, Y: Ytrain})

    print(sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X:Xtest, Y:Ytest}))
```

The console prints `nan` as the result. I investigated the input `dtype` and found to be `float64` which is correct. I searched for the solution and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103581/tensorflow-optimizer-gives-nan-as-ouput).
This doesn't seem to be working in my case. It still gives the same results.

On a side note, the data been imported using numpy are maximum 4 digit positive integers (if that helps). Kindly, help in debugging the issue.

Comment: What does your data look like ?

Comment: Yes, the data is going out of limits of the data structure. When I scaled the data by 1000. I got the code working.